# I would like to know the average temperature of the universe as a function of time in equation format?

Tags: cosmology, temperature

This would give the analysis of the amount of dark energy as predicted by equation.

Comment: It’s easier using redshift: $T_0(1+z)$. Conversion to time is a bit complicated because it depends on assumptions (like flat universe or not, I believe)

Comment: If you had such an equation, how would it predict the dark energy?

Comment: It wouldn’t do any such thing.

Comment: yes my equation would predict the amount of dark energy at any time in the universe within 95% accuracy(because some of the energy would be dissipate in the medium of exchange) , i have a paper on hold for review on this soon it would get published. I wanted this so that i could prove myself right doing the mathematics.

Comment: Also i am looking for an endorsement on arxiv for the paper if anyone would be of any help.

Comment: @G.Smith i would be happy to share my research with you if you can give me an endorsement.